# Python Imports doesnt give output in PHP

Tags: php, python, shell

PHP code

```
<?php 
echo shell_exec(' python /Users/rushikesh/Sites/hello2.py ');
>?
```

Python code

```
print('hello')

import numpy as np

print('hello2')
```

It outputs only hello, why does the code doesnt give any output after import statements.

I even tried finding error

```
echo shell_exec(' python /Users/rushikesh/Sites/hello2.py ');
```

But still am getting blank output after import statements

Comment: How can you tell which `print('hello')` is being echoed in php?

Comment: Earlier part is being echoed because i tried changed the print statements

Comment: Please check if you are executing the file which you've shown above, also try changing the string from 'hello' to anything to check which line is not executing

Comment: I have tried, earlier code is being executed before the import statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
putenv('PYTHONPATH=/Users/rushikesh/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages:');

$command = escapeshellcmd('/Users/rushikesh/anaconda3/bin/python /Users/rushikesh/Sites/hello2.py');


output = shell_exec($command);

echo $output;
```

Found from answer of '[call python script *with non-standard library imported* from php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13617715/call-python-script-with-non-standard-library-imported-from-php)'

Comment: According to that question, the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable might not be set when using this script on a server. So setting it might be required, making this the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use `python -u` to skip Python's output buffer, but that still doesn't quite help if Python's library path is incorrect (exit status 3221225477). This works:

```php
PHP start.
<?php 
$cmd = 'c:/python36-32/python -u hello.py';
echo shell_exec($cmd);
?>
PHP end.
```

```py
print("Hello!")
#import sys; print(sys.path)  # Can we even find numpy?
#help('modules')  # Slow, so use -u flag for Python.
import numpy
print("Imported numpy.")
```